# How can I use the distanceTo method provided in leaflet in my custom library that I want to create based on it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, leaflet

I am using leaflet in my project. Now there is this **distanceTo** method which basically calculates the distance between the two coordinates. Now I want to create separate JS file which will have a function called getDistance() and I want to keep the logic of calculating the distance between the coordinates separately. Here is the code

**FILE a.js**

```
function getDistance() {
var getDistanceCal = (L.Layer ? L.Layer : L.Class).extend({
    calculateDistance: function (latA, latB) {
        if (latA !== undefined && latB !== undefined) {
            
            //How can I make it run distanceTo method here where leaflet Js is being called in another file 
            let dis = latA.distanceTo(latB);
            let distanceConversion = ((dis) / 1000).toFixed(0);
            let distanceKm = distanceConversion;
            return distanceKm || 0;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

});

L.markerDistance = function () {
    return new getDistanceCal();
};

return L;}
```

In my another file where leaflet.js is called, I am calling it :

**FILE b.js**

```
CALLING THE FUNCTION
markerDistanceFunction().markerDistance().calculateDistance(1.3521, 103.81) // should give distance but throws an error that distanceTo is not defined
```

I am trying to extend the leaflet but something is going wrong. Could someone please have a look and let me know how to make it work.

Some links:

[Extend leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html)

[DistanceTo](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#layer)

Any help would be appreciated. Big thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you make this so complicated.

I recommand to create a normal function instead of extending a class.

```
function calculateDistance(latA, latB) {
        if (latA !== undefined && latB !== undefined) {
            
            //How can I make it run distanceTo method here where leaflet Js is being called in another file 
            let dis = latA.distanceTo(latB);
            let distanceConversion = ((dis) / 1000).toFixed(0);
            let distanceKm = distanceConversion;
            return distanceKm || 0;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }


distance = calculateDistance(latlng, latlng);
```

But to answer your question, the problem is, that `distanceTo` only works with the `L.LatLng` class and not with a normal number.

`markerDistanceFunction().markerDistance().calculateDistance(L.latLng(1.3521, 103.81),latlngFromMarker)`

And when you want to overwrite the default `distanceTo` function [src](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/dd832105697c98c1fca5475616377cda66f876be/src/geo/LatLng.js#L75):

```
L.LatLng.prototype.distanceTo = function (other) {
    return (L.CRS.Earth.distance(this, L.latLng(other)) / 1000).toFixed(0);
}
```

Comment: Wonderful!! I did the same. I used a readymade code for calculating distance. Thank you man.